# "Peer pressure" badge doesn't appear in my profile page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, badges

I was notified that I had gotten the "peer pressure" badge, and was told to see my profile. I did and that badge doesn't appear there. I think maybe I've experienced that before with another badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear in your profile:

- https://askubuntu.com/users/19779/jo-erlend-schinstad?tab=activity&sort=badges
- https://askubuntu.com/users/19779/jo-erlend-schinstad?tab=badges

Comment: It does now. Why the delay? It seems a little strange that it wouldn't appear immediately when I'm asked to look for it.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad I do not know. Maybe a caching issue. Did you try a forced refresh?